# Python: opening a separate instance of IDLE from within an IDLE file

Tags: python, python-idle

I have had success opening external application files from within a python script by sending the application filepath and the filepath of the specific file as a list to Popen as follows:

```
filepath = ["C:\\ProgramFiles\\LibreOffice\\program\\scalc.exe",
"C\\FolderName\\filename.xlsx"]
subprocess.Popen(filepath)
```

What I am trying to do, similarly - from within a python script in IDLE - is to open an external python file in a new instance of IDLE. I found a file called idle.py as well as idle.pyw and idle.bat - so I tried all three - following is an example:

```
filepath =["C:\\Users\\frank\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Lib\\idlelib\\idle.py",
"C:\\Users\\frank\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\HelloWorld.py"]
subprocess.Popen(filepath)
```

This (using idle.py) resulted in: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application. I got a similar error with idle.pyw.

Using idle.bat, the application did actually open in the idle editor, but did not run. So I would have to manually run it in that case.

Is there a way to have the file open in a new instance of IDLE and run automatically?

Comment: To get your launched instance of IDLE to automatically run the specified file, you need to put a `"-r"` parameter before the filename.

Comment: Many thanks. I've tried this and it doesn't work - probably not doing it right. Can you show me explicit code? Instead of \\HelloWorld.py what should it look like?

Comment: Just insert `"-r"` as the middle element of the list you're passing to `Popen()`.